# How can I force connection to my home wifi verses public wifi?

Tags: settings, wifi

I get some wifi signal from a hotspot outside my building from my cable company. But I only want to connect when my home wifi is out of range. How can I set a prefered order of wifi connections?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no option to select a prefered wifi network. The only thing you can do is remove the open hotspot from your list and manually reconnect when you need it.

I do understand your need for this. Consider [voting for this feature](https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/5041466-enable-wifi-connection-order-preference) on http://windwosphone.uservoice.com

Comment: Removing the hotspot is not necessary (with 8.1 at least). Just remove the checkmark to automatically connect in the WiFi settings.